# Centrado de texto con boostrap en reactjs

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, reactjs

Intento centrar el texto del `<h3></h3>` mediante Boostrap en Reactjs, pero no logro se ponga a la derecha o que se centre.

```
<div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <h3 className="text-center">Time to play</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="card-group col">
                    {/** Impresión del sustantivo */}
                    <div className="card">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

al div con la clase row agregale justify-content-center para centrar el contenido dentro de ese div

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <p>Texto Centrado</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Funciono. (Y)